# Swiftmailer removes dot after www inside content

Tags: html, swiftmailer

Swiftmailer often removes the `.` from `www.` from links inside my mail.

This occurs randomly, I've noticed.

The following often outputs `wwwdomain.com`, without the `.` after `www`

The `href` url itself is always correct, but not the text link inside of it.

See the `<a>` tag in the middle:

```
<!-- START MAIL FOOTER -->
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="background: #f6f6f6;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="background: #f6f6f6;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="5" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 100; color: #8c8c8c; padding: 15px 10px 25px 10px; text-align: center; line-height: 20px; color: #8c8c8c;">
                        <a href="https://www.domain.com/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #8c8c8c;">
                            this mail was sent from <span style="color:#009dab;">www.domain.com</span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="5" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- END MAIL FOOTER -->
```

Comment: I can't imagine, why (or even how) Swiftmailer would do that. Are you sure there problem isn't somewhere else, e.g. a typo in a cached version of your HTML?

Comment: @RoToRa Hmm, I've changed the filename of this included footer file, and it seems fine now! Does Swiftmailer have some caching on its own though?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I've only always used it in combination with Symfony, which does cache almost everything.

Comment: @RoToRa Well, thanks. You can make it an answer if you want.